# C++ Multiple Inheritance Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I need to know something about the constructor. I didn't really know how to phrase the question, but basically I need to have all the action happening in the constructor of the final class, whilst a variable gets created in the constructor of one class and used in the constructor of another. Does this work, and is it safe? Example code below.

```
// Init class
class cInit {
private:
    std::string *m_X;

public:
    cInit() { m_X = new std::string; }
    std::string *getX() { return m_X; }
};

// Does this work (?)
class cUse {
private:
    std::string *m_X;

public:
    cUse(cInit *x) : m_X( x->getX() ) { }

// Final Class - same question here? Does it work?
class Final : public cInit, public cUse {
public:
    Final() : cInit(), cUse( this ) { }
}
```

Comment: Why `std::string*` pointer instead of a plain member?

Comment: Erm. Right. Try it and see?

Comment: @g-makulik i think thats just for demonstration purpose

Comment: Is the intend to pass a reference of `m_X` instantiated in `cInit` to `cUse` for manipulation? Then a `std::string&` would be the right choice for `cUse::m_X` and needs to be initialized from it's constructor.

Comment: The string class is for demonstration purposes as paranaix stated. In reality it's another class. Point being I need to initiate everything in the constructor. However m_X won't be used until later, I just need the pointer and everything in place.

My big concern is the usage of "this" inside the constructor and the chained subclass constructors.

Comment: @SirRogers Your concern is eligible and I've mentioned this in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since base constructors are called in declaration order, `cInit::cInit()` will be called first. Its constructor would assign `cInit::m_X` member.

Then, `cUse::cUse(cInit *)` will be called and would assign a result of call to `cInit::getX()` to `cUse::m_X`. Given that `cInit::getX()` is not a virtual function, it is safe to call it like that.

In other words, there is nothing wrong with this code. Except that it is ugly (or should I say not well designed?), confusing, and would only cause troubles further down the road.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh I know just how badly designed it is, kudos to working on legacy software. I'm not the original coder, but I have to make changes to a rather bad codebase, and instead of changing and possibly bugging everything, I try to keep the changes as small as possible.

Why does it matter whether it's a virtual function or not? I could still call it in the final class constructor if it's a virtual function right, but not inbetween constructor calls?

Comment: @SirRogers: Yes, because otherwise a vtable might be used before it is actually constructed and some haywire call or pure virtual call is made.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, and everyone else, for posting.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer the following design (as it's more [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) oriented):

```
// Init class
class cInit {
private:
    std::string m_X;

public:
    cInit() : m_X() {}
    std::string & getX() { return m_X; }
};

class cUse {
private:
    std::string& m_X;

public:
    cUse(std::string &x) : m_X( x ) { }
```

> // Final Class - same question here? Does it work?

In your sample you're using `this`, which isn't completely constructed at that point, though `cInit` already is. With vtables (virtual function definitions), usage of `this` will certainly fail.
Try the following instead:

```
class Final : public cInit, public cUse {
public:
    Final() : cInit(), cUse( cInit::getX() ) { }
}
```

You can also use pointers as in your original sample, but I'd strongly discourage to use raw pointers all along. Better choose a `std::unique_ptr` (`std::auto_ptr` with pre [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standard) for `cInit::m_X` and a raw pointer for `cUse::m_X`.